# get value of global variable inside function from another file.py

Tags: python, module, global-variables

file_a.py

```
def timestamp(value1, value2)
  global date1, date2
  
  (...)

  date1 = 01/01/01
  date2 = 02/02/02
```

---

file_b.py

```
import file_a

timestamp(value1, value2)

get_date = date1
```

And I get this error:

**NameError: name 'date1' is not defined**

---

I've tried to call as:

```
file_a.timestamp(value1, value2)
```

And it doesn't work.

Comment: I think you need to initiate the global variable outside the function in file_a.py by keeping the value `date1 = None`. In file_b.py, you can simply call that variable using `from file_a import *`. This shall work.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so the issue you have is related to the way Python handles imports and variable scopes. When you import variables from let's say `file1` using `import file1`, you are importing the functions and variables from `file1` into `file2`, but they are not automatically available in the global scope of `file2`. So you'll have to access the value of date1 by referencing it with `file1`. Here is how you'll do it:

file1.py:

```
def timestamp(value1, value2):
    global date1, date2
  
    date1 = 1
    date2 = 2
```

file2.py:

```
import file1
file1.timestamp(1, 2)  # Call the function to set date1 and date2

print(file1.date1)  # Now date1 should be available here
print(file1.date2)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It solved the problem, by getting the result as you suggested >> print(file1.date1)
Thanksss